# What's wrong with this Height Map in Unity?

Tags: unity, heightmap

In the first picture it seems the virtual surface of the normal map is calculated to behind the camera. I only have this bug on convex surfaces.

However in both these pictures it seems the surface of the normal map is floating above the original texture. It duplicates the surface instead of replacing it.

I really don't know what's going on here.

## Rendering output

[image][image]

## Shader Settings

[image]

## Texture and Heightmap

[image]
[image]

The Height Map was created in Photoshop:

[image]

## Heightmap Import Settings

[image]

Comment: It's hard for us to diagnose the issue given only two stills. Can you please include the textures you're using, and show us how you've configured your material or shader?

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear until we have more information on the textures and shader. ^

Comment: Shaders and textures added. Anything else?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've imported your bumpmap as a normal map, [following the steps in the docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterNormalMap.html). Can you check whether the problem persists after you change the Texture Type to Normal Map, check Create From Grayscale, and click Apply? Or are you trying to use it as a displacement map?

Comment: I'm sorry, I seem to have confused bump maps with height maps. My normal maps (bump maps) work just fine. Its the height map thats bugging me. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: The third picture in my post under "Shader Settings:" shows Albedo, Normal, Height and Occlusion maps. Since the textures are mostly grey they are hard to notice.

Comment: You've referred to a bump map a few times in your post but appear to be suggesting it's actually a height map. Could you double check the references to a bumpmap are accurate? There's currently three of them.

Comment: Fixed. Again, sorry. Foolish of me

Comment: Have you tried disabling reflections? That's what it looks like its trying to do.

Comment: Disabling reflections in the shader settings doesn't change anything

Comment: The problem might be clearer in this footage: https://youtu.be/B0KUGsXtT1g

Comment: Just throwing ideas at the wall, but does the problem remain if you disable mip-mapping and aniso on the wall textures?

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem